# How to use more than just if/else in ternary operator?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having trouble with writing the right syntax for this **ternary operator**. I want to put like three 'if statements' and one 'else statement'.

But as far as I know, the ternary operator is only working with if/else.

How to correct the mistakes in that code?

```
Text(
              (browns == true && blacks == true && whites == true)
              ? 'Proportion: $browns agutis : $blacks pretos : $whites albinos'
              : (yellows == true && yellows == true && blacks == true)
                  ? 'Proportion: $yellows dourados : $blacks pretos : $browns chocolates'
                  : (reds == true && yellows == true && blacks == true)
                      ? 'Proportion: $reds coloridos : $whites brancos'
                      : 'Invalid proportion',
                 
            ),
```

**Edit** (showing more code):

```
body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              brownBlackWhites
                  ? 'Proportion: $browns agutis : $blacks pretos : $whites albinos'
                  : brownYellowBlack
                      ? 'Proportion: $yellows dourados : $blacks pretos : $browns chocolates'
                      :
                      // else if
                      redWhite
                          ? 'Proportion: $reds coloridos : $whites brancos'
                          // else
                          : 'Invalid proportion',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'courier',
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  height: 2.5,
                  letterSpacing: 0.7),
            ),].),),
```

image according to the first code snippet:
[image]

Comment: You're using commas instead of colons to separate the "then" and "else" operands.  That is, you want: `(browns && blacks && whites) ? 'string1' : (yellows && blacks) ? 'string2' : (reds && yellows && blacks) ? 'string3' : 'Invalid proportion'`.

Comment: I edited my answer based on your comment but it is still not working. It displays 'Invalid proportion'

Comment: Displays "Invalid proportion" for what values?  Your original question is about the syntax, not about the logic.  That part is up to you...

Comment: Verify the values u got (browns, blacks, ...) are includes inside the condition

Answer (score 0):

`if (browns == true)` same as `if (browns)` so you can store your conditions in three variables for more readability

```
    final brownBlackWhites = browns && blacks && whites;
    final yellowBlack = yellows && blacks; // I think depend on your login you should add `&& browns` 
    final redYellowBlack = reds && yellows && blacks;
    Text(
      // if
      brownBlackWhites
          ? 'Proportion: $browns agutis : $blacks pretos : $whites albinos'
          :
          // else if
          yellowBlack
              ? 'Proportion: $yellows dourados : $blacks pretos : $browns chocolates'
              :
              // else if
              redYellowBlack
                  ? 'Proportion: $reds coloridos : $blacks pretos : $browns chocolates'
                  // else
                  : 'Invalid proportion',
    )
```

**Edit**

remove dot  from that line

```
   ),].),),
```

to be

```
 ),]),),
```

**Edit 2**

```
final browns = colors.where((color) => color == Colors.brown).length;
final brownBlackWhites = browns == true && blacks == true && whites == true;
```

here Is the problem the type of browns is int so `browns == true` won't work because the '==' compare two same type and this case you compare int with boolean

Comment: Hey, I tried using the syntax you put there but it appears that the program is not considering the variables you created. Even if, for example, brownBlackWhites is true, it displays 'Invalid proportion'.

Comment: show me your code

Comment: I added more code to my question. Let me know if you need a github repository

Comment: I edit my answer, see it

Comment: Oh, it was actually a typo when I was making the edit. The code still doesn't work. I'll create a GitHub repository to make things easier.

Comment: https://github.com/viguinijpv/punnet_calculator/blob/main/lib/screens/result/result.dart   --> starts in line 93

Comment: I saw you repo, look Edit 2  in ansewer

Comment: Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: sure, it's a logical error so first I want to know what you want to do

Comment: So, the app displays 16 strings (each one is called a `gen`). The strings' colour changes depending on the input of the user. I want to count how many of each colour we have inside this 16 `gen` (the result) and display the proportion of it (such as 9:4:3, for example). But before counting, it has to check if the colour exists in that result - all the possible colors are already in the code.

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you want to do

Comment: I want to check if the colours exist before counting them. I need to count these colours because I want to display the proportion of each one on the screen - e.g.: `"Proportion: color1 : color2 : color3"`. I've just edited the question and added an image so you can see it better.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use a **builder widget** and make the code readable and maintainable without fighting with **ternary operators**. ternary operators hard to understand and maintain if there are more than one condition.

```
Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          String text = '';
          if (browns == true && blacks == true && whites == true) {
            text =
                'Proportion: $browns agutis : $blacks pretos : $whites albinos';
          } else if (yellows == true && yellows == true && blacks == true) {
            text =
                'Proportion: $yellows dourados : $blacks pretos : $browns chocolates';
          } else if (reds == true && yellows == true && blacks == true) {
            'Proportion: $reds coloridos : $whites brancos';
          } else {
            text = 'Invalid proportion';
          }
          return Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'courier',
                fontSize: 20.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                height: 2.5,
                letterSpacing: 0.7),
          );
        })
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Example of using Two or many conditions in Ternary Operator

```
const isValue = (_value) => _value > 100 ? "Greater Than 100" : _value < 100 ? "Lower Than 100" : "Equal to 100";


console.log(isValue(120)) // Output => Greater Than 100

console.log(isValue(50)) // Output => Lower Than 100

console.log(isValue(100)) // Output => Equal to 100
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBWRl.jpg)